# Thrust/CUDA reduce_by_key gives non-deterministic result

Tags: c++, cuda, reduce, thrust

I'm facing a problem with the `reduce_by_key` function of the **Thrust** library. It looks like a bug to me but I'd like to be sure before reporting.

First, my setup: CUDA 7.0, Windows 8, NIVIDA GeForce 820m. The whole thing is compiled using Visual Studio 2010 and `nvcc` in release mode, 64bits.

Now, the exercise that illustrates the problem.

I have a vector of random numbers called `devData` generated on my device.
I tabulate a vector of indices called `devIndices` of the same size defined as follows:

- `devIndices = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... K-1, K-1, K-1, K-1}`
- `devData = { 1, 4, 5, 7, 5, 8, 9, 6, ... 7, 8, 9, 6}`

So that each value in **devIndices** is repeated **mod = 4** time in this example.

Then, I just want to `reduce_by_key` `devData` using `devIndices` to obtain the reduced vectors that follow:

- `devIndices = {0, 1, ..., K-1}`
- `devData = {17, 28,..., 30}`

(if I'm right with the arithmetic :) )

Now, I know for sure that the elements of `devIndices` should sum up to a value `T` given by the following relation:

- `T = [(K-1) * K /2]` (ex: `[0 1 2 3] -> 6 = (K-1)*K/2 = 3 * 4 /2`)

I tried to do this on my machine and it works fine for small numbers of elements but it fails for large ones. (`100,000` fails...)

Below is the code I use to manipulate my two vectors as described above and output the sum of `devIndices` at the end. You can play around with the parameter `k` that basically sets the number of elements.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <fstream>
typedef typename thrust::device_vector<int>     tDevVecInt;
typedef typename thrust::device_vector<float>   tDevVecFlt;

struct rando : public thrust::unary_function<unsigned int, float>
{
    unsigned int mainSeed;
    rando(unsigned int _mainSeed):mainSeed(_mainSeed) {}
    __host__ __device__ float operator()(unsigned int x) 
    {
        unsigned int seed = x * mainSeed;
        thrust::random::taus88 mac(seed);
        thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(0,1);
        return dist(mac);
    }
};

struct modSim : public thrust::unary_function<int, int>  
{
    int sz;
    modSim(int in)
    {
        this->sz = in;
    }
    __host__ __device__ int operator()(const int &x) 
    {
        return x/sz;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    int mod = 10;
    int k = 10000;
    int szData = k*mod;
    
    tDevVecFlt devData(szData, 0.);
    tDevVecInt devIndices(szData, 0.);
    
    thrust::transform(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), thrust::make_counting_iterator(0) + szData, devData.begin(), rando(123456789));    
    thrust::tabulate(devIndices.begin(), devIndices.end(), modSim(mod)); 
    thrust::reduce_by_key(devIndices.begin(), devIndices.end(), devData.begin(), devIndices.begin(), devData.begin());
    std::cout << thrust::reduce(devIndices.begin(), devIndices.begin()+ k, 0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Worst of all: when I run several times the same piece of code, I get different results! The random vector has nothing to do with this (it is seeded... and I checked it by the way).

So the question part now:

- Am I wrong somewhere? `reduce_by_key` seems the right tool to me.
- Can anyone reproduce this irreproducibility?
- If this is indeed a bug, what is the usual way to report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I wrong somewhere?

The [documentation](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga1fd25c0e5e4cc0a6ab0dcb1f7f13a2ad) for thrust::reduce_by_key states:

> Precondition The input ranges shall not overlap either output range.

You have broken that precondition in your code:

```
thrust::reduce_by_key(devIndices.begin(), devIndices.end(), devData.begin(), devIndices.begin(), devData.begin());
```

So your code is broken, and is not representative of anything demonstrating a thrust bug.  `thrust::reduce_by_key` is not a thrust operation that can be done in-place.

Comment: "I don't see anything that would provide the sum of devIndices in your code." there is a `thrust::reduce` which sums up the reduces indices

Comment: Thank you for your help! You're right. Concerning the sum of devIndices, I do one more reduction that I output at the end.

Comment: Oops.  I missed the last thrust::reduce